# Xamarin.Forms - Call Master Page from a defined button

Tags: xamarin.forms, master-detail

I would like to know if it's possible to call the **`Master`** (not `Detail`) **`Page`** from a `button` defined in **XAML** by example?

It's possible to call it (`MasterPage`) from the button generated (*in the top of `DetailPage`, but in bottom from WinPhone*) by Xamarin but me, I want, for private reasons, to avoid this button generated by Xamarin DetailPage, and make my own button (I can put where I want, CrossPlateform).

Thank for your answer !

Comment: by "call MasterPage" - do you mean toggle it's appearance?

Comment: Make it appears, like when you click on the navbar button (top/left)

Comment: then use the IsPresented property that Rodrigo mentions below

Comment: Ok I'll, but what about the menu generated? I mean the Navbar (Android/iOS on Top, WinPhone on Bottom). Can I delete/hide it? To make my own design

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the [MessagingCenter](http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/xamarin-forms/messaging-center/).

Setup a `Subscribe` in the `Master Page` to do what you want and `Send` a message when the button is clicked.

Note (to your comment): To Open the MasterDetailPage´s Menu, set the [IsPresented](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/property/Xamarin.Forms.MasterDetailPage.IsPresented/) property to `true`.

Comment: Thank for your answer. Ok but how can I call the Menu after that? How to make it appears?

Comment: Set IsPresented to True in your MasterDetailPage instance.

Comment: Okok, I check that tomorrow :) Can I also delete/hide the menu generated? I mean the Navbar (Android/iOS on Top, WinPhone on Bottom)